# Paracompact topological space: Why is $\overline{V}_s=F_s$?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Question: Why do they say in the remark that $\overline{V}_s=F_s$?

Attempt: The only explanation I can think of is that the union $V_s=\cup_{s(t)=t} A_t$ is finite, and I tried to prove it using the fact that $\{A_t\}_{t \in T}$ is locally finite, but I've failed trying to prove this. Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion $F_s \subset \overline{V_s}$ is always true. The other inclusion is true for locally finite collections. Note that if $x\in \overline{V_s}$ and $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ that meets only $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n$, by the neighborhood criterion of the closure, you get $$x\in\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline{A_i} \subset F_s.$$